# Rsync copying current directory with name

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, cp

I want to copy current directory to my backup directory:

I tried this command `rsync -a . ~/backup/` but it just copies the current directory contents instead of creating new directory at the destination.

I know creating new directory at the destination end can be achieved by avoiding the trailing slash in source path. But it does not work in my case since I am using a period(".") instead of directory name.

I want rsync to create a new directory at the destination path with name same as the current directory. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like your script but, if needed, you can do it by command line directly from the current directory:

```
rsync -a "$PWD" ~/backup/
```

or in a way similar to your script approach with

```
rsync -a "$(pwd -P)" ~/backup/
```

**Notes:**

- It is needed to quote the current directory if in the path is present, for example, one or more spaces.
- In case of symbolic links in the path it is possible to obtain the *physical* path avoiding all the *symlinks* specifying the option `-P` in the `pwd` command invocation (`$(pwd -P)`), or calling the executable with its full path (`$(/bin/pwd)`).
  Indeed there exists the *built-in* `pwd` that by default shows the *symlinked* path, and the executable `/bin/pwd` that by default shows the *physical* path.
- Both commands refer to the variable `$PWD` that contains the *the present working directory* when they are asked for the version of the path with the eventual *symlinks*: so if you do not strictly need the *physical* path, you can avoid to call the *subshell* and use directly the variable `$PWD`.

  ```
  rsync -a "$PWD" ~/backup/
  ```

Comment: This is better solution..! Actually I just wanted to create an alias like ("backupme") So I can easily take backup of current directory by executing that command. This command is very useful and now I am going to remove that script and use this instead. Thank You..!

Comment: This command works! But when I am creating an alias and executing that alias it just takes the backup of my home directory instead of current directory.

Comment: Try to use single quote `'` in the alias definition: `alias BACKUPNOW='rsync -a $(pwd) ~/backup/'`

Comment: Examples often are [better than words](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6697845/3569208). It is not in aliasing, it is in bash. ;) Till you are curious do a wide use of `man bash` (or another command) or `help alias` if the command is a built-in... Ok `man bash` is a wide output  to start with... but in general you can do it.

Comment: Oh! when I use double quotes it expanded inside the alias definition okay understood. Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks, this works great. But when path of current directory contains space it breaks. So it's better to always use `pwd` with double quotes `"$(pwd)"`.

Comment: @NavidHt Thanks for the spot. Updated. Note that you can avoid at all the subshell with the use of the variable PWD, `"$PWD"`.

Comment: I had to add / to "$PWD" for it to work for delete as well

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution:

Created a new shell script like this:

```
current_dir=`pwd`
dir_name=`basename $current_dir`
rsync -a . ~/backup/$dir_name
```

and when executing this it will create a new directory at the destination and copy current folder contents.

Comment: Clear and understandable script. Usually you can find the suggestion to use the `syntax current_dir=$(pwd)` instead of `current_dir=\`pwd\`` for compatibility reasons even if they perform the same action.